# How to identify syslog message senders?

Tags: logging, server, client, network-protocols, syslog

I am writing a small syslog server.

Is it possible to identify specifically the sender of a syslog message when I receive it?

I do not want to rely on the ip address since it can change.

I could write a syslog client which will send the MAC address as well in the syslog message. However, this solution is very limited as it would work with other manufacturer's devices.

How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [RFC3164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164) mentions that logs should have `hostname` in the logs. Make sure you have correct hostname set and also updated `/etc/hosts` with the same hostname. Logging will pick up this hostname and add it to the logs.

Comment: how about logs that i receive from networking equipements like cisco router or switches or other devices which are basically not computers ?

Comment: Routers and switches are distributed systems (OR you can call it a very large computers), they collect the logs internally from all the blades/cards and send them to external syslog server. As far as these routers and switches support syslog, they should comply to RFC standards, and if they don't sending hostname, better open a ticket on them. I am ex-cisco and the product i worked, used to support this functionality.